# Не используется вся память в windows-10-64

Tags: windows, windows-10

Добрый день.

Введение в проблему:

Есть ноутбук ACER Pentium четырехядерный довольно новый (CPU N3540 покупал полтора года назад). На нем стояла Windows-8 после покупки она проапгрейдилась до Windows-10-64 Home Edition. При покупке на ноуте было 2 гига ОЗУ я, как рачительный хозяин, поставил вместо 2 гигов ОЗУ 8 гигов. Теперь windows-10-64 честно рапортует что видит 8 гигов ОЗУ. Но в мониторе ресурсов использование ОЗУ никогда не бывает что система использует больше чем 2 гига, как бы я не нагружал машину. То есть похоже что система хоть и видит мои кровные 8 гигов но использовать их не хочет.

Вопрос:

1. Может ли Windows-10-64 Home Edition использовать более чем 2 гига ОЗУ? Или я зря потратил 3.5 тыщи рублей на покупку восьми гигов? :-(

Спасибо

Comment: протестируйте средствами винды свою оперативку ну или любыми другими способами

Comment: Windows 10 Home Edition x64 может использовать до 128 GiB RAM.

Comment: @Aliaksandr Pitkevich Попробовал запустить тест ОЗУ встроенный в Windows. Два раза запускал тест и два раза тест шел но в конце не выходил из теста и не загружал Windows снова. Приходилось перезапускать машину.

Comment: а как вы поняли, что тест не дошел до конца?

Comment: @Aliaksandr Pitkevich Тест начинается и идет но мне пришлось отойти потому что слишком долго он идет, а когда я подошел к машине то машина висела. Первый раз машина висела с темным экраном. Второй раз на экране был логотип биоса ACER как при загрузке, но машина все равно висела.

Comment: там был выбор режима проверки?

Comment: Никак не могу найти, как выйти из аккаунта на этом сайте. Какие-то рейтинги, награды, бронзовые звезды, учетные карточки членов КПСС, а простого выхода из аккаунта нет. :-(

Comment: @Aliaksandr Pitkevich Да, там был выбор режима проверки. Но я запустил стандартный тест. Еще были простой и широкий тест, еще предлагалось включить или выключить кеш и еще были какие-то опции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Всего существуют три режима проверки памяти:**

*1. Basic (Основной), включающий в себя тесты:*

```
MATS+
INVC
SCHCKR (со включенным кэшированием)
```

**Проверка памяти в Основном режиме обычно продолжается несколько минут.**

*2. Standard (Стандартный), при котором кроме тестов Основного режима проводятся также тесты:*

```
LRAND
Stride6 (со включенным кэшированием)
SCHCKR3
WMATS+
WINVC
```

**Проверка памяти в Стандартном режиме может продолжаться около часа.**

*3. Extended (Расширенный) – включает все тесты Стандартного режима, плюс тесты:*

```
MATS+ (со включенным кэшированием)
Stride38
WSCHCKR
WStride-6
CHCKR4
WCHCKR3
ERAND
Stride6 (с выключенным кэшированием)
CHCKR8
```

**Проверка памяти в Расширенном режиме может занять несколько часов.**

Comment: Ну вот я запускал стандартный тест который Windows предлагает по умолчанию и похоже что после прохождения теста машина повисла. Это очень странно потому что вобщем-то нареканий к работе машины у меня нет, кроме той странности, которая была описана в вопросе. А именно: хотя система показывает, что она видит все 8 гигов ОЗУ, монитор ресурсов никогда не показывает, что используется больше, чем 2 гига ОЗУ.

Comment: час прошел с момента запуска теста? то что висит - вовсе не означает что висит)

Comment: Когда тест идет то на экране идет прогресс-индикатор. А когда машина повисает, то на экране или ничего или логотип биос.

Comment: Час прошел с момента запуска теста?)

Comment: Сейчас еще раз попробую запустить тест хотя бы в простом режиме чтобы так долго не ждать.

Comment: Запустил тест в Basic режиме. Все прошло нормально, винда перед тестом перезагрузилась, тест прошел, после теста винда нормально поднялась и сообщила что тест ОЗУ проведен и ошибок не обнаружено. Но в процессе тестирования нигде не было написано, сколько именно памяти тест протестировал. Может он и протестировал только два гига из установленных восьми гигов.

Comment: а в биосе что пишет гляньте

Comment: Разве в биосе есть что-то про тест ОЗУ? Или поглядеть сколько ОЗУ видит биос? Сейчас погляжу.

Comment: Биос видит все восемь гигов ОЗУ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60581/discussion-between-aliaksandr-pitkevich-and-pepsicoca1).